# Replacing a text in PDF with a new value with JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, pdf-generation, filereader

I have a PDF file and I will use it as a template. There is a title that says "NAME_SURNAME". I wanted to create a pdf file from template with the fullName in the request body, when there is a request. I thought it might be something like this:

```js
import pdfFile from "./template.pdf"


app.post("/newPDF", async (req, res) => {
    const { fullName } = await req.body;
    pdfFile.replaceText("NAME_SURNAME", fullName);
}
```

It supposed to be that simple but that's not I guess :) Is there any package for or any easy way to replace texts in the PDF file?

I tried HummusJS, File Reader etc. but I stuck.